# Got Destiny Legendary edition. Can't redeem those 3 weapons, neither the dlcs

Tags: ps3, destiny

yesterday I got Destiny Legendary edition. It came with 2 folders. One with the taken king's code, and another one with 3 weapons. I redeemed them on PSN, I could "download" that 100kb something, but I can't find the 3 rifles in the game ( the orange ones ), neither the dlcs. Is this going to be unlocked after I reach some level in the game ??

I'm level 4 or 5 I guess.

I'm from Brazil, and my CD has everything in Portuguese ( the text ) so I think everything is from here.

Ps3 player here.

Answer (score 1):

If the weapons are legendary weapons then you will get access to them once you attain level 20, however if these weapons are from one of the expansions like Taken King then you could be looking at access at level 40